# Searching for number inside of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Forgive me, I am not quite skilled and fairly new to the language and programming practices. I am creating a button which prompts the user to enter a number once the number is entered, I create a for loop that iterates through the same amount as the number. For example, the user enters 4 and the screen will display 0 1 2 3  and then I have a button that asks the user to enter a number to see if that number exists in the previous array. So if the user entered 3 it would dispay "it exists" if they entered 5 it would display "number not found". Should I create an array to store the iterations and then run that array through a function that searches for the number. Looking for guidance, thank you for the help guys.

```js
     function getNumber() {
      
      var el = document.getElementById("demo");
    
      // Get the user's input and convert it to a number
      var n = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"),10);
      
      // Set up a string that will become the output.
      var output = " ";
    
      
      // loop through given number
      for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
        
        // variable containing iterations
        output += i;
        //var numArray[i] = output;
      }
    
      //display iterations
      el.textContent = output;
    
    }
    
    function findNumber(){
     var sn = parseInt(prompt("Search for number"),10);
    
     for(var j = 0; j < sn; j++){
    
     }
    
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="getNumber()">Click!</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick ="findNumber()">Click!</button>
```

Comment: To get the desired result, all you need to test is whether the second number entered is less than the first number entered. Storing all the numbers in the range in an array is a needlessly complicated way of doing it.

Comment: I feel like it's a little more in depth. I know that he wants use to implement a binary search function to see if the entered number exists in the previous array.

Comment: @LeopoldStoich *he* who?

Comment: My professor. My understanding is that if the user entered 4 it wouldn't be found because the array starts at 0.

Comment: But if the array will always be populated with every number in the range from 0 to *x* there is no point searching through the array. If you had an array populated with random numbers that would be a different question...

Comment: I see now, yikes. I was overthinking it completely.

Comment: @LeopoldStoich that's silly. If all numbers are in order like `0,1,2...` than it makes no sense. if otherwise you're asking the user for a number on each iteration - and those numbers are inserted inside your array than a simple google `find if number is in array` would lead you to the right solution. Wouldn't it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. For the sake of simplicity, I'll use a global variable here.

```js
     
     // A global variable to store user input
     var userInput;        
     
     function getNumber() {
      
      var el = document.getElementById("demo");
    
      // Get the user's input and convert it to a number
      var n = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"),10); 
      
      // Store the user's input to our global variable
      userInput = n; 
      
      // Set up a string that will become the output.
      var output = " ";
    
      
      // loop through given number
      for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
        
        // variable containing iterations
        output += i;
        //var numArray[i] = output;
      }
    
      //display iterations
      el.textContent = output;
    
    }
    
    function findNumber(){
        var el = document.getElementById("result");
     var sn = parseInt(prompt("Search for number"),10);
        
        // If number is within the range
        if (sn < userInput) {
          el.textContent = "it exists";
        } 
        
        // If number is not within the range
        else {
          el.textContent = "number not found";
        }
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="getNumber()">Click!</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick ="findNumber()">Click!</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your `n` variable global
Than compare if `sn` is higher than `n`

```js
var n; // Make it global

function getNumber() {

  var el = document.getElementById("demo");

  // Get the user's input and convert it to a number
  n = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number"), 10);

  // Set up a string that will become the output.
  var output = " ";


  // loop through given number
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    // variable containing iterations
    output += i;
    //var numArray[i] = output;
  }

  //display iterations
  el.textContent = output;

}

function findNumber() {
  var sn = parseInt(prompt("Search for number"), 10);
  var isHigher = sn > n; // n is now accessible in this function
  var message = isHigher ? "Not found" : "Number found!";
  alert( message );
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getNumber()">Click!</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="findNumber()">Click!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this theoretic example, it's true that you only need to check if the second number entered is smaller than the first number. If you want to search for a number in an array of any numbers, you can use the javascript indexOf function. See example below:

```js
var arr = [1,6,77,888];

if (arr.indexOf(66) > -1) {
 alert('number is in array');
} else {
 alert('number is not in array');
 }
```

Comment: The code in this solution `arr.indexOf(66) > 0` will miss the element at index 0.

Comment: Good catch. Edited.

Comment: Actually this is what my professor was looking for. He just realized he didn't specify that we are supposed to return the index of the searched number if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

To search an array, use the `indexOf()` method of a JavaScript array. The original post gives an example populating the array with `myArray[x]=x`, creating options pointed out by other solutions. Presuming you want to search a more general case of an array, you could use `indexOf` directly or define a function that returns `true` or `false`:

```
function inArray(myArray, queryValue) {
    return myArray.indexOf(queryValue) > -1;
};
```

Arrays in JavaScript are objects with some additional methods like `pop()`, `indexOf()`, etc. JavaScript objects are associative arrays; this solution only applies to Array objects. Array objects are constructed with the `[]` literal or the `Array()` constructor. Arrays can only have properties named by ints, unlike other JavaScript associative arrays. See [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html).